# Python - map() to split and get first part only

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `csv` from which I read through pandas `read_csv`,

`data = pandas.read_csv(file)`

Now a small subset is like this,

`data['interest']:`

```
one.a
two.a
three.a
four.b
```

and so on...

I want to create a new `pandas` series, say,

`data['i']` which contains only the first part of `data['interest']`, that is,

```
one
two
three
four
```

Now I can loop through the entire thing and `split`, but can I do it with map?

Something like - `data['i'] = map(split_and_get_first_part, data['interest'])`?

Comment: Is "one.a" a string, and you just want to split on the '.' character? Is there a specific reason to use map instead of a list comprehension, and did you try writing `split_and_get_first_part` already?

Comment: `lambda x: ".".join(x.split('.')[:-1])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `map` method:

```
data['interest'].map(lambda x:x.split('.', 1)[0])
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'interest':['one.a', 'two.a', 'three.a', 'four.b']})
data['i'] = data['interest'].map(lambda x:x.split('.', 1)[0])
print(data)
```

yields

```
  interest      i
0    one.a    one
1    two.a    two
2  three.a  three
3   four.b   four
```

Comment: You are genius. I don't know why I didn't think about using the `map` method!

Comment: The `split(".", 1)[0]` optimization instead of `split(".")[0]` is worthy of another comment and praise.

Comment: Hi @unutbu - Can you help me with this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951840/pandas-groupby-and-create-new-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
map(lambda s: s.split('.')[0], data['interest'])
```

But it still has to iterate over the entire list so, while its more concise than a `for` loop, it's not necessarily more efficient.  It's possible that `map` is a more efficient way of looping than `for` in this case, but you'd have to do some tests to see if that is the case.  It's worth noting that in Python 3, `map` returns an iterator rather than a list, so, depending on what you're doing with it, it may well be more efficient in Py3.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
split_and_get_first_part = lambda x: ".".join(x.split('.')[:-1] if '.' in x else x
data['i'] = map(split_and_get_first_part, data['interest'])
```

This covers a few corner cases, like strings with more than one dot or no dot at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to splt strings and return first part... like this

```
def split_first_part(str):
    return str.split('.')[0]

map(split_first_part, data['interest'])
```