# Pandas - Groupby and create new DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, data-analysis

This is my situation -

```
In[1]: data
Out[1]: 
     Item                    Type
0  Orange           Edible, Fruit
1  Banana           Edible, Fruit
2  Tomato       Edible, Vegetable
3  Laptop  Non Edible, Electronic

In[2]: type(data)
Out[2]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

What I want to do is create a data frame of only `Fruits`, so I need to `groupby` such a way that `Fruit` exists in `Type`.

I've tried doing this:

`grouped = data.groupby(lambda x: "Fruit" in x, axis=1)`

I don't know if that's the way of doing it, I'm having a little tough time understanding `groupby`. How do I get a new `DataFrame` of only `Fruits`?

Comment: Aside: IMHO, step # 1 should be breaking your "Type" up into (choosing better names, of course) "Edibility" and "Kind_of_Stuff".  It's usually better to split columns like that right at the start as a real column is both easier and safer to work with-- avoids problems like "Not Edible, Definitely Not a Fruit", which contains "Fruit".

Comment: @DSM Ofcourse, I'm not using my real world data here. This was the best way I could get the problem description suited to my needs, In the real world data that I have, it's kind of complicated, and `Type` is an arbitrary length CSV.

Comment: I didn't think you were really working with data about whether bananas were edible.  ;^)  The point stands: using string containment is a bug waiting to happen, even if it seems like it isn't a problem with your data, because it doesn't cause any problems until it does.

Comment: @DSM, haha sure! Advice taken! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
data[data['Type'].str.contains('Fruit')]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['Orange', 'Banana', 'Tomato', 'Laptop'],
                     'Type':['Edible, Fruit', 'Edible, Fruit', 'Edible, Vegetable', 'Non Edible, Electronic']})
print(data[data['Type'].str.contains('Fruit')])
```

yields

```
     Item           Type
0  Orange  Edible, Fruit
1  Banana  Edible, Fruit
```

Comment: `x.str.contains('something')` - Nice!  I really need to remember pandas's vectorized string functions. They're quite handy.

Comment: `data[data.Type.apply(lambda x: 'Fruit' in x)]` appears to be a tad bit faster than `data[x.str.contains('Fruit')]` on my machine (195 µs per loop vs 209 µs per loop). So `str.contains` appears to just be syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thank you for informing me the optimization as well!

Comment: @unutbu contains will be much faster for a larger dataset as its cythonized IIRC

Comment: @Jeff: That's odd. I just tested this on `pd.concat([data]*1000)` and found `str.contains` to be 2x slower than `apply(lambda x: 'Fruit' in x)`. Perhaps my version `0.12.0-933-g281dc4e` is too old?

Comment: The difference is that these are actually slightly different operations. contains is more like this: ``reg = re.compile('Fruit'); data[data['Type'].apply(lambda x: bool(reg.search(x)))`` (also contains handles ``nan``

Comment: @unutbu maybe should add a flag to contains ``regex=True``, so can do this w/o the regex too, want to make an issue?

Comment: @Jeff: How would you feel about a PR changing `str_contains` to `str_search` and adding a "new" function `str_contains` which performs the non-regex operation?

Comment: I would leave str_contains, maybe add it as ``str.in`` or ``str.isin``

Answer (score 5):

`groupby` does something else entirely. It creates groups for aggregation.  Basically, it goes from something like:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b']
```

to something like:

```
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c']]
```

What you want is `df.apply`.

In newer versions of `pandas` there's a `query` method that makes this a bit more efficient and easier.

However, one what of doing what you want is to make a boolean array by using

```
mask = df.Type.apply(lambda x: 'Fruit' in x)
```

And then selecting the relevant portions of the data frame with `df[mask]`.  Or, as a one-liner:

```
df[df.Type.apply(lambda x: 'Fruit' in x)]
```

As a full example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Orange', 'Edible, Fruit'],
        ['Banana', 'Edible, Fruit'],
        ['Tomato', 'Edible, Vegtable'],
        ['Laptop', 'Non Edible, Electronic']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Item', 'Type'])

print df[df.Type.apply(lambda x: 'Fruit' in x)]
```